# How to create a custom e-mail containing an order summary?

Tags: magento-1.9, blocks, email, email-templates

## Synopsis

I have been building an abandoned cart e-mail, which is almost working.  I have been struggling with the transaction e-mails and blocks.

I have a table that will be populated with prospects whom abandon their basket which after 7 days will be contacted.  A cron will run every day and send the e-mails.

## Observer and E-mail Template

The observer I have:

```
/**
 * Aggregate abandoned carts and e-mail them.
 *
 * @param Varien_Event_Observer $observer
 * @return void
 */
public function emailAbandonedCartCustomers($observer)
{
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('cartabandonment/email_queue_collection')
        ->addFieldToFilter('status', Example_CartAbandonment_Model_Email_Queue::STATUS_PEND);

    foreach ($collection as $customerQuote) {
        $quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore(
            $customerQuote->getQuoteEntityId()
        );

        $data = new Varien_Object();
        $data->setData(array(
            'quote' => $quote->getData(),
            //'items' => $quote->getItemsCollection(),
            'items' => $quote->getItemsCollection()->toArray(),
        ));

        //Zend_Debug::dump($data);
        //Zend_Debug::dump(get_class_methods($quote));
        //Zend_Debug::dump($data->getData('items'));

        $emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');

        $emailTemplate->setDesignConfig(array('area' => 'frontend'))
            ->setReplyTo($this->_getHelper()->getSender())
            ->addBcc($this->_getHelper()->getBcc())
            ->sendTransactional(
                $this->_getHelper()->getEmailTemplate(),
                $this->_getHelper()->getSender(),
                $customerQuote->getEmailAddress(),
                null,
                array('data' => $data)
            );


        die('Testing Process');

        if ( ! $emailTemplate->getSentSuccess()) {
            Mage::throwException($this->_getHelper()->__('E-mail was not sent.'));
        }
    }
}
```

The transaction e-mail has been loaded and configured in the admin console:

```
Hi {{var quote.customer_firstname}},

You have not completed your purchase, would you like to checkout now?

{{block type='core/template' template='email/example/abandoned_items.phtml' products=$items}}
```

The contents of *email/example/abandoned_items.phtml* are:

```
<? print_r($products) ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using `Mage::register` and `Mage::registry`.

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->loadByIdWithoutStore(
    $customerQuote->getQuoteEntityId()
);

$data = new Varien_Object();
$data->setData(array(
    'quote' => $quote->getData(),
));

Mage::register('abandoned_cart', $quote);

$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
```

Inside the E-mail template you would need to collect this object:

```
<?php
$_quote = Mage::registry('abandoned_cart');
$_collection = $_quote->getItemsCollection()->toArray();
?>
```